# is there any C++98 compiler which works for Windows NT?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++98, visual-studio-6

I am working in a project which needs to run in a Windows NT, the application must be implemented in C++98. Currently we only have Visual Studio 6 but we are having many problems with basic syntax statements.

Do you known any alternative compiler which can comply with the c++98 standard and works in an ancient system as Win NT?

We already tested Watcom but is not usefull either...

Comment: Maybe Turbo C++?

Comment: VC++ 6  was pretty far from C++98. The last VS version to target NT was 2005, and the C++98 support in that was reasonably complete. The only question is where you can lay your hands on a license. (It's included in some subscriptions to visualstudio.com.)

Comment: thanks! 2005 coud be a better option, I will try to get a license from my company

Comment: Borland C++ Builder 4 was brilliant for that era. I'm not sure if it's possible to acquire it still though.

Comment: If you want Borland C++ Builder you can find copies on https://archive.org/ and https://winworldpc.com/ - I haven't tried any of them.